# Asp .Net web Forms File upload (Without flash control)

Tags: c#, jquery, webforms, telerik

It seems chrome going to stop support for Flash control this year-end. I'm using asp net web forms.
My existing system developed by using flash control. It appears as follows.
[uploading progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKoAi.png)

[Uploaded files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEWli.png)

This is the HTML table

I adding my controller from code behind

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl UploadHolder = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)item.FindControl("UploadHolder");

System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl cmdSpan = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("span");

RadAsyncUpload radAU = new RadAsyncUpload
{
    ID = "teleriUpload" + Int_Crt,
    MultipleFileSelection = Telerik.Web.UI.AsyncUpload.MultipleFileSelection.Disabled,
    OnClientAdded = "OnClientFileUploading",
    OnClientFileUploaded = "OnClientProgressUpdating",
    OnClientFileUploadFailed = "OnClientFileUploadFailed",
    OnClientFileUploading = "OnClientFileUploading",
    CssClass = "ButtonBrowse" + ((submitDoc != null) ? " ButtonBrowseReplace" : " ButtonBrowseNew"),
    OnClientProgressUpdating = "OnClientProgressUpdating",
    ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static,
    MaxFileSize = Int32.Parse(criteria["Size"].ToString()),
    EnableFileInputSkinning = false,
    AllowedFileExtensions = fileTypes.Split(','),
    OnClientFileUploadRemoving = "OnClientFileUploadRemoving",
    OnClientFileUploadRemoved = "OnClientFileUploadRemoved",
    EnableInlineProgress = true,
    TemporaryFolder = Server.MapPath("~/"),
    ManualUpload = true,

    HideFileInput = true
};
cmdSpan.Controls.Add(radAU);
```

I need to show this controller as my existing controller shows on the chrome.
I'm using Telerik RadAsyncUpload control.
but it always showing as follows. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mz35h.png)
The uploaded list showing near the controller. I need to move it to my Uploaded File column the same as before. Please help me anyone is there did this before

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to allocate more space for the control to render properly. Can you increase the Width and Height of its parent element/container?

Also you can use the DevTools HTML and CSS inspector to find out which CSS class is causing the issue and to override it. Check out this blog post we created for such cases:

https://www.telerik.com/blogs/improve-your-debugging-skills-with-chrome-devtools#inspect-the-generated-html-of-a-control

https://www.telerik.com/blogs/improve-your-debugging-skills-with-chrome-devtools#see-the-applied-styles

You can disable the flash by setting the DisablePlugins="true" property as explained in https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/asyncupload/functionality/disable-plugins.

Please note that in the modern browsers the upload happens with the help of the browsers' FileAPI only in IE are used Forms for upload.

Rumen from Telerik